# If $m \ge 8 s \log(m^2 s)$, how much greater $m$ is relatively to $s$?

Tags: logarithms

Given that $m,s \in \mathbb{N}$, if $m \ge 8 s \log(m^2 s)$, how much greater $m$ is relatively to $s$ ?

It seems to me $m>>s$, but I would like some idea of the magniture.
I'm not quite sure how to attack this problem.

This is obviously equivalent to $m \ge 16 s \log(m) + 8 s \log(s)$.

Maybe an idea is to see how much $m$ has to grow when $s$ increases by 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $m::=16ts$, the inequation turns to

$$16ts\ge8s\log(256t^2s^3),$$
or, dividing by $16s$ 
$$t\ge4\log2+\log t+\frac32\log s$$
and taking the exponential,
$$\frac{e^t}t\ge16s^{3/2},$$
or
$$(-t)e^{-t}\ge-\frac1{16s^{3/2}}.$$

Then, using [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (secondary branch, decreasing),

$$-t\le W\left(-\frac1{16s^{3/2}}\right),$$
$$m\ge-16W\left(-\frac1{16s^{3/2}}\right)s.$$

Comment: f is not a bijection.

Comment: Take the largest branch.